Unity TextMeshPro not showing up in an Android build
Whenever I make an Android build all of the TextMeshPro text doesn’t load at all, it works fine in the editor and on a PC build. I have already attempted a number of suggested issues like setting Instancing Variants to ‘Keep All’ and making a new scene and new fonts to test if it was an issue with a 3D text using the font. But whenever I’ve tested a new scene or new font it still doesn’t show up. I’ve updated TextMeshPro and also uninstalled the package and reinstalled it and it still doesn’t work. I have no clue what’s going on and I’m worried it might be something tickbox in the build settings that will make it impossible to debug.
Error Log:

Also if there’s any more information needed then I can provide it.
Version: 2022.3.2f1

tbh it sounds more like it stems from that top line of textprovider and cant get to the url..

Do you have other addressable assets? Do they work? Are there any errors in the build log when you build for android?

There's a folder called AddressableAssetsData that has autogenerated, should I just delete it? Also there's no errors on build too, it builds without issue, @Erik

No you don't need to delete it. Try reading the documentation for building for Android, might have something, I don't have much more to help with, good luck!
